# Using filter method to extract from an array the numbers which have an exact gap between each other

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
primes.filter((value, index) => value[index] + g === value[index + 1]);
```

Greetings.. I have an array `primes` with some prime numbers within a certain range and I have `g` which is the step or gap I need to filter by. I want to return an array with the consecutive primes that have this particular number gap between each other. For example if the gap is 4.. then I need to return `[7, 11]`. Not sure how to use `filter` in this case.. obviously what I tried doing is not working. Also.. it would be even better if I can return only the first occurrence of such gap.

Comment: If you only want the first occurrence, then don't use `filter`.

Comment: If you want to return both of those numbers, you need to check in both directions: `primes.filter((value, index) => value[index] + g === value[index + 1] ||  value[index] - g === value[index - 1]);`, otherwise only `7` will show up, since `11 + 4` is not a prime.

Comment: First, about the code you have: `value` is the value of the current prime during the iteration. So `value[index]` is certainly not going to work, maybe you meant to do `primes[index]` (which is equal to `value`). Then, please provide some example inputs and the desired outputs

Comment: @blex well for example this array named primes: `[307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397]` .. and i want to use `filter` to return only the primes that have a step of `8` .. so for example `[359, 367]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is close, but the `value` is simply the value at the current index, so you can't use it to access other values in the array. Instead, the third argument you pass to the `filter` callback can access the array.

The other issue you have is that, if you want to get *both* numbers, you'll probably want to check the revers (i.e., if a number is `g` greater than the previous number).

You'll see here that this returns all instances that match, so if you only wanted the first instance I would recommend using an array method like `find` rather than `filter`.

```js
const g = 4;

const primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19];

const filtered = primes.filter((value, index, arr) => {
  return value + g === arr[index + 1] || value - g === arr[index - 1];
});

console.log(filtered);
```

If you *did* indeed want only the first match, you could just use the `find` method to get the first value and you would know that the second value is `g` greater than the first.

```js
const g = 4;

const primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19];

const first = primes.find((el, index, arr) => el + g === arr[index + 1]);

console.log([first, first + g]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There were three problems in your code:

1: `value` is not an array

2: it needs to work both ways to get both 7 **and** 11

3: you need to assign something to the filtered value (apparently)

This should work:

```js
var primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17];
var g = 4
result = primes.filter((value, index) => value + g == primes[index + 1] || value - g == primes[index-1]);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const primes = [307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397];
const g = 8;

// Assuming they're in order, and you don't care about non-consecutives
const resA = primes.filter((v, i) => v + g === primes[i + 1] || v - g === primes[i - 1]);
console.log(resA); // [359, 367, 389, 397]

// Works with an unordered Array, but more greedy
const resB = primes.filter((v, i) => primes.some(n => Math.abs(v - n) === g));
console.log(resB); // [359, 367, 389, 397]
```